# Impala ACID table select ERROR: Operation not supported on transactional (ACID) table:

Tags: hive, transactions, impala, acid

I'm using impala 3.4 directly with hive 3.1.

The problem is that if you create a general table in the hive and then select it in impala, an error occurs.

The error message is as follows:

```
Query: show tables
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| customer |
| lineitem |
| nation   |
| orders   |
| part     |
| partsupp |
| region   |
| supplier |
| t        |
+----------+
Fetched 9 row(s) in 0.02s
[host.cluster.com] default> select * from customer;
Query: select * from customer
Query submitted at: 2020-11-20 09:56:12 (Coordinator: http://host.cluster.com:25000)
ERROR: AnalysisException: Operation not supported on transactional (ACID) table: default.customer
```

In the hive, the acid table and the orc table are only concerned with whether to delete or update, but I knew that selection is common.

In fact, the select statement is normally executed through hive jdbc. Only impala would like to help you understand why this error occurs.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-8347 ?

Comment: orc table also can't read

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It was confirmed that the table created through Hive in impala operates normally.

There are two possible causes:

1. Connect impala built with Hive2 to Hive 3 databases.
2. When creating a Hive Table that I did not recognize, set the default flag related to ACID.

Answer (score 0):

This version can't read ACID table wich are created by Hive. Hive creates ACID table by default.